# Can org-mode export all files in a directory?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

If I tweak the latex/css style file used by org-mode, is there a way to re-export all the org files in a directory?

I have previously manually exported all the files.

Comment: Are you using `org-publish` or have you manually exported all the files previously?

Comment: Do you mean some sort of batch execution? http://orgmode.org/manual/Batch-execution.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can start with this version. There are inconveniences: it pollutes kill ring and visits all org files.

```
(defun publish-dir-org ()
  "Publish all org files in a directory"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (mapc
     (lambda (file)
       (with-current-buffer
       (find-file-noselect file)
     (org-export-as-html-batch)))
       (file-expand-wildcards  "*.org"))))
```